# Assert two different types of enumerations are equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have an NUnit unit test which I have two collections of different types which I want to assert are equivalent.

```
class A { public int x; }
class B { public string y; }

[Test]
public void MyUnitTest()
{
    var a = GetABunchOfAs(); // returns IEnumerable<A>
    var b = GetABunchOfBs(); // returns IEnumerable<B>

    Assert.IsPrettySimilar(a, b, (argA, argB) => argA.ToString() == argB);
}
```

where `Assert.IsPrettySimilar` is defined like such

```
public static void IsPrettySimilar<T1, T2>(
    IEnumerable<T1> left, 
    IEnumerable<T2> right, 
    Func<T1, T2, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var leftEnumerator = left.GetEnumerator())
    using (var rightEnumerator = right.GetEnumerator())
    {       
        while (true)
        {
            var leftMoved = leftEnumerator.MoveNext();

            if (leftMoved != rightEnumerator.MoveNext()) 
            {
                Assert.Fail("Enumerators not of equal size");
            }

            if (!leftMoved)
            {
                break;
            }

            var isMatch = predicate(leftEnumerator.Current, 
                                rightEnumerator.Current);

            Assert.IsTrue(isMatch);
        }           
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a more idiomatic way of doing the above with the existing methods in NUnit?  I already looked at `CollectionAssert` and there's nothing matching what I want to do.

My description of "equivalent" in this case is:

1) Collections must be of same size
2) Collections must be in same logical order
3) Some predicate must be used to determine equivalence between matching items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think what you are trying to test. You are not trying to test that objects from first sequence are same as objects from second sequence. They can be very different. So, word *similar* is very vague here. What you really trying to test here, is that some projection of first sequence is equal to other projection of second sequence. And NUnit already have such functionality:

```
 CollectionAssert.AreEqual(bunchOfAs.Select(a => a.ToString()),
                           bunchOfBs.Select(b => b));
```

Thus you are projecting both sequences to get particular data, then you can give nice names for these two projections, which will make your test readable to others. You have some hidden business logic here, which does not have explanation in code - you don't explain *why* you making such projections. So, nice names of projection results will explain your intent. E.g:

```
 var expectedNames = employees.Select(u => u.Login);
 var actualNames = customers.Select(c => c.Name);
 CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedNames, actualNames);
```

That is much cleaner for me than

```
 Assert.IsPrettySimilar(employees, customers, (e, c) => u.Login == c.Name);
```

Comment: This is correct, I am testing that the projections are what I expect.  However, in my scenario, my two types have 7 and 4 properties, respectively.  The two examples you have do not account for the order or count, which is something I need to take into consideration.

Comment: @Matthew but `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` verifies both count and order of items - it will throw assertion exception when one of sequences has missing item (i.e. it's shorter than other) or when some items are not equal (its internal implementation of `EnumerablesEqual` is pretty much same as yours extension method, except of predicate usage)

Comment: Ah okay, this looks like it might do what I want then, let me investigate.

Comment: This looks like it does what I want, however, I'm probably not going to use it as in my examples I find the predicate to be more idiomatic to the tests that I write, but this is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I know you looked into `CollectionAssert`, however, I have found a strategy like this very useful in my own tests.

Overriding ToString and Equals on the objects makes this test pass.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{

    [Test]
    public void MyUnitTest()
    {
        var a = GetABunchOfAs(); // returns IEnumerable<A>
        var b = GetABunchOfBs(); // returns IEnumerable<B>

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a, b.OrderBy(x => x.y));

    }

    public List<A> GetABunchOfAs()
    {
        return new List<A>
        {
            new A() {x = 1},
            new A() {x = 2},
            new A() {x = 3},
            new A() {x = 4}
        };
    }

    public List<B> GetABunchOfBs()
    {
        return new List<B>
        {
            new B() {y = "4"},
            new B() {y = "1"},
            new B() {y = "2"},
            new B() {y = "3"},

        };
    }
}

public class A
{
    public int x;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().Equals(x.ToString());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return x.ToString();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string y;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().Equals(y);
    }

}
```

I deliberately left GetABunchOfBs out of order, however the test still passes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Sergey's answer is the one I'm looking for (which was to see whether NUnit already has a facility to do what I want).  However, this is the solution I ended up with, which is closer to the implementation I want.

```
public static class EnumerableAssert
{
    public static void AreEquivilent<TExpected, TActual>(IEnumerable<TExpected> expected, IEnumerable<TActual> actual, Func<TExpected, TActual, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(expected, actual))
        {
            return;
        }

        using (var expectedEnumerator = expected.GetEnumerator())
        using (var actualEnumerator = actual.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var expectedMoved = expectedEnumerator.MoveNext();

                if (expectedMoved != actualEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    Assert.Fail("Expected and Actual collections are of different size");
                }

                if (!expectedMoved)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Assert.IsTrue(predicate(expectedEnumerator.Current, actualEnumerator.Current));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer I've found for situations where the objects involved can be equivalent for the purposes of the test but not equal and are _not_ possible to project in a reasonable way — for example, wanting to compare Roslyn syntax nodes for non-trivial equivalence.